# Can we play 2 videos at the same time

Tags: android, video, android-source, exoplayer, hardware-acceleration

I can able to open two application at a time using multi window free from.
But I trying to play videos at a time in both application,but its not happening.

Can we play two videos at time.
in the s905x data sheet I have seen that it supports multi decoding sessions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this, using nuplayer we can play number online streaming videos at a time.